# python urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I want send data to remote server using python .

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib

import urllib2

url = 'http://dev.bambeeq.com'

values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)

req = urllib2.Request(url, data)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

the_page = response.read()
```

after run this program . i got this error

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.
```

If you know the answer. please let me know.

Thanks for reading..

Comment: What do you expect the remote server to do with this data? Is it configured to accept and understand your message?

Comment: save the data in sqlite

Answer (score 2):

A `403` error means that you do not have access to the information the site contains. From Wikipedia:

> A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action. Status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access, for some reason, to the requested resource by the client.

Now, this is not a Python problem, but rather a problem with the webserver itself, perhaps you need to add a username and password to the `values` list.

Comment: how can i add username and password?

Comment: @Anand I'm afraid that I do not know. You will need to consult the owners of the site, as to what should be the names of the parameters you pass in your GET request, so that you may access the server.

Comment: Ouch.. I think you really can't access the site, unless you are acquinted with the site creator somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is server side at http://dev.bambeeq.com/
The site returns 403 to me too so if you get get the webserver working as intended you can retry the script.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the http server log? (if it is Apache, normally tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log or similar, to take a detailed look about what's going on).

For example, I solved this using "poster" library. (just "pip install poster")

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
import urllib2

register_openers()

datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"file": open("hello_world.txt", "rb")})
request = urllib2.Request("http://server.url/extras/upload_file.php", datagen, headers)
try:
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.fp.read()
```

But as you can see, the url where I am sending the file is not just a directory: In the server side there is a piece of code (upload_file.php) waiting for post data:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: ". $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
?>
```